# Kafka batching configuration is not consistent

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm trying to maximize the amount of data I'm batching from Kafka. The output is me writing the data to a file on server. I'm adding extremely high values to my consumer configuration and I'm still getting multiple files written with very small file sizes.

As seen below, I wait a long time to retrieve my min bytes. After ~20 seconds the poll completes with N records and writes a pretty small file. I'm interpreting that as the wait time not being respected nor is the min bytes. Why would this be the case?

### Code:

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, args.enableAutoCommit);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG, args.minFetchBytes);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG, args.maxFetchBytes);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, args.maxPartitionFetchBytes);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, args.maxPollRecords);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG, args.maxFetchWait);
```

Consumer configuration:

```
--max_fetch_bytes 2147483000
--min_fetch_bytes 2147483000
--max_poll_records 2147483000
--max_partition_fetch_bytes 2147483000
--enable_auto_commit false
--fetch_max_wait 900000
```

Comment: You didn't tell us what is timeout set to in `consumer.poll(long timeout)`.

Comment: 1000 ms is the poll duration

Answer (score 0):

[here's](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/server/DelayedFetch.scala#L83) a list of things that can terminate a DelayedFetch early:

```
/**
* The operation can be completed if:
*
* Case A: This broker is no longer the leader for some partitions it tries to fetch
* Case B: The replica is no longer available on this broker
* Case C: This broker does not know of some partitions it tries to fetch
* Case D: The partition is in an offline log directory on this broker
* Case E: This broker is the leader, but the requested epoch is now fenced
* Case F: The fetch offset locates not on the last segment of the log
* Case G: The accumulated bytes from all the fetching partitions exceeds the minimum bytes
* Case H: The high watermark on this broker has changed within a FetchSession, need to propagate to follower (KIP-392)
* Upon completion, should return whatever data is available for each valid partition
*/
```

note that case F may happen on segment roll broker-side - how often are those for you?

Answer (score 0):

Add this configurarion to your consumer:

```
max.poll.interval.ms=3600000
```

If it does not work, add those as well:

```
connections.max.idle.ms=3600000  
default.api.timeout.ms=3600000
```

Now the batch should wait for maximum one hour.

Comment: I did max.poll.interval earlier and got a consumer wakeup exception after processing my initial batch.. Any reason why that would happen? The config is tricky